# Create table comparing Two Queries with identical fields/field names

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m, powerbi-desktop

I would like to create a table to compare Month To Date (MTD) Vs YTD Sales data metrics

I am using two queries:

- 1st query = YTD Sales data (Two fields: Sales and Quotes)
- 2nd query = MTD Sales Data (Two Fields: Sales and Quotes).

Each query has the same field names, just different data

I would like to output a table like the following

[image: Example pic of Table Needed]

How to I create the above table? At the moment I can only create a table like the following:

[image: Example Pic of Current "Wrong" Table]

The latter 1x4 table only works if I appropriately name the fields. But definitely isn’t what I want, because with enough fields, the table could go on forever.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the query editor, create a label column for each table that labels what they are and then append the two tables together so you get something like this:

[image: Append Tables]

Then you can create a matrix visual with the `Label` column in the Columns field and the `Sales` and `Quantity` columns in the Values area.

Make sure you've switched "Show on Rows" to "On" under the Format > Values section of the Visualizations pane.